# Windows 10 startup repair not working but where are boot files located?

Tags: linux, windows, boot, partitioning

I have a PC which has Windows 10 and Linux Mint installed for dual boot.  One day, I decided I need to log into Windows, but was presented with the Automatic Repair process - which didn't help.  I've tried various solutions, but to no avail.

I get the message Access Denied when trying to run the command 'bootrec /fixboot'.  I've also tried assigning a temporary drive letter to the EFI partition (FAT32 100mb) via diskpart to run the commands suggested on some of the solutions out there, but again no luck.  I've also formatted that drive, but was a bad move, as that messed up the GRUB Linux boot info.  Luckily, I took an image of my drive before attempting to repair Windows boot.

Using Macrium and only restoring the main NTFS C: partition, 100mb EFI and 529mb Recovery partitions took it back to where it was (that is - able to boot into Linux, but Windows goes into boot repair).

With an older image of this drive, I decided to restore only those three partitions mentioned above and was able to successfully boot into Windows and Linux.  However, as the main Windows partition was over a year old, it does not contain newer files and recent programs installed since that image was taken.

So I tried to restore ONLY the Windows partition from the recent image, but got the dreaded 'Preparing Automatic Repair' message.

My next step was to restore the older bootable image, copy the files & folder from Windows/Boot folder (which contains the EFI folder) to USB, then restore newer Win partition, then (from Macrium's WinRE USB environment) used xcopy to copy those files from Windows/Boot to (what I thought was corrupted) Windows/Boot folder of recent Win partition .... unfortunately, this didn't work either.

Question is - where are the boot files I should be looking at from my known good image?

Would really appreciate any help to get me back into my recent Windows partition.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your current Windows installation is corrupted and might not be easy
to repair.
However, you have a working Windows backup, although it dates from
a year ago.

I suggest to restore the year-old partition, then just update
your own data from the newer backup. Macrium should have the ability
to selectively copy files, or to mount the backup as a virtual disk
for copying the files.